# How to send IMAGE/MEDIA messages on WhatsApp Web?

Tags: javascript, automation, whatsapp

I want to send media files or images with caption using Whatsapp URL like below:

`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${PHONE_NUMBER}&text=${encodeURI(MSG)}`

With the help of above URL, we can send custom messages to any PHONE_NUMBER (even if PHONE_NUMBER is not added as contact).

I want to send media files through this URL.

Disclaimer:

1. I don't want to use any Automation tool like Selenium, Puppeteer or any WhatsApp API.

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For sending images or medias through WhatsApp along with a caption without using selenium, you can try sending it using python.
Here I've used python language for sending message.

Requirements:

- WhatsApp cloud API developer account
- Access token
- phone ID

```py
from heyoo import WhatsApp

messenger = WhatsApp('YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN',phone_number_id='YOUR-PHONE-ID')

messenger.send_image('IMAGE-LINK','91**********') //For sending image 

messenger.send_image(image="IMAGE-LINK",
recipient_id="91**********",
caption="This is a caption.") //For sending image with caption
```

Comment: I hope this helps you https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwilk8KY6fb_AhWt4jgGHe4rD5wQtwJ6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dx85ba0VYsYo&usg=AOvVaw2SX4wc476B0ChXUZYgFMt0&opi=89978449 - @Aamir