# How to automatically attach media (pictures) and send it as WhatsApp message programatically?

Tags: javascript, php, android, reactjs, whatsapp

I'm developing a React JS project where I need to send a message via WhatsApp. I'm currently using this method:

```js
let msg = 'This is an interesting caption.';
let mobile = '+628123456789';

let url = `whatsapp://send?phone=${mobile}&text=${msg}`;

Linking.openURL(url).then((data) => {
  console.log('WhatsApp Opened');
}).catch(() => {
  alert('Please make sure WhatsApp installed on your device');
});
```

I want to automatically attach a certain picture along with the caption/message like when you click on the 'Share via WhatsApp' button in Mobile Legends game.. is it possible to do this without using WhatsApp Cloud API?

P.S.:

- looks like this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72264185/1235167) but it hasn't had any answers yet even after 3 months..
- I'm using Codeigniter 4 as the backend, so if it's not possible using javascript perhaps it can be done with PHP or Codeigniter?